# Convert TZ date received from Angular in Scala backend

Tags: angular, typescript, scala, datetime

I'm sick of datetime problems between 2 languages.

Angular send dates only in TZ format (`2021-09-06T11:25:39.000Z`), but my Scala backend is not capable to use it in `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
def formattedDate(input: String, format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"): String =
    new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(input))
```

> Error:
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-09-06T11:25:39.000Z"
> ```

How can I solve this?

thx

Comment: Use `ZonedDateTime.parse` instead.

Comment: Angular can send date in whatever format you want, you just have to format the date on the frontend as a string.

Comment: Also don't use `SimpleDateFormat` it's a deprecated API: use `java.time` API instead.

Comment: And finally the pattern you wrote doesn't match the sample string you provided: the `T` and timezone is missing. You should be able to reuse default date format `ISO_DATE_TIME` with `java.time`.

Comment: I avoided to change the default format of js/ts date (`new Date()` or `mat-datepicker` which I use, will send TZ format in json body). I don't knew about java.time, I see is more easy to use than SDF. Make one comment as answer to can accept it. Thanks